# AWS API Gateway + AWS Lamdba + Entity Framework Core + PostgreSQL Aurora RDS An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a serverless application using the following stack. 
- AWS API Gateway 
- Proxied to Lambda functions running .NET Core using Entity Framework Core for PostgreSQL to do reads or writes to PostgreSQL Aurora.

Every so often - without code changes or any infrastructure or other changes, I get the following error on a database query/savechanges().

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
 ---> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<FillBufferAsync>g__InternalFillBufferAsync|215_0[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 min, Int32 initial)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|0>d.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at LCSApi.Functions.PostCustomerProxyResponse(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context) in C:\Users\JMatson\source\repos\LCSSolution\testapi\Function.cs:line 426
```

I can't find a reason for this. I am running a fairly vanilla database first scaffolding of the database. The only thing that seems to cause it to occur is when I haven't invoked my API method for a few minutes. The first call has this error, then any done after work fine. They continue to work fine unless I don't invoke for a few minutes.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I think it's an issue with the way lambda is torn down and Postgres. E.g. nothing to do with EF as I have the exact same issue not using EF.

Comment: One "fix" for this is to add `Pooling=false;` to the connection string. This does mean that DB operations will generally be slower as the TCP connection will have to be re-established for every query/ command.

Comment: I definitely won't be doing that Durdsoft - I want pooling on, as it's much more efficient for my use case of having potentially many lambda functions running concurrently and connecting to the DB. I want as much connection re-use as possible. This transient error - although ugly in the logs - seems not to have a lot of operational effect as the retry after 0ms seems to ensure the underlying command is executed.